# Why am I getting this error suddenly Connection Dispose?

Tags: c#, sql

The transaction associated with the current connection has completed but has not been disposed. The transaction must be disposed before the connection can be used to execute SQL statements.

```
protected string installDatabase(string connectionString, bool createSampleData,string scriptpath)
{
    //uncomment this line to support transactions
    using (var scope = new System.Transactions.TransactionScope())
    {
        string scriptsFolder = scriptpath + "\\install\\Scripts";
        string createDatabaseFile = string.Format(@"{0}\{1}", scriptsFolder, "Campus.sql");
        string error = proceedSQLScripts(createDatabaseFile, connectionString);
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(error))
        {
            return error;
        }
        scope.Complete();    
    }
    return "true";
}      

protected string proceedSQLScripts(string pathToScriptFile, string connectionString)
{
    List<string> statements = new List<string>();
    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
    conn.Open();
    using (Stream stream = File.OpenRead(pathToScriptFile))
    using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream))
    {
        string statement = string.Empty;
        while ((statement = readNextStatementFromStream(reader)) != null)
        {
            statements.Add(statement);
        }
    }
    try
    {
        foreach (string stmt in statements)
        {
            {
                SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(stmt, conn);
                command.ExecuteNonQuery(); 
                //conn.Close();
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return ex.Message;
    }
    finally
    {       
        conn.Close();
    }
    return string.Empty;
}
```

Comment: Please add the language tag.

Comment: *Where* do you get that error?

Comment: string error = proceedSQLScripts(createDatabaseFile, connectionString); here i got this error !       (The transaction associated with the current connection has completed but has not been disposed. The transaction must be disposed before the connection can be used to execute SQL statements.)

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code

```
 Finally
     {
        conn.Close();
        conn.Dispose(); 
    }
```

Comment: This answer does not explain how it solves the question.  Please attempt to explain a bit more, and preferably show where this code should be inserted into the Poster's code.

Comment: Yes it goes into finally block then i got this error here  ( string error = proceedSQLScripts(createDatabaseFile, connectionString))